# Implementing search functionality in a database application

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, ado.net

I am creating a database application in vb.net where I need to implement a search functionality that should search the whole database and return the user with a list of records found in the databse that contains the search string in a DataGridView control.

I used one combobox with name: "colNames" and a textbox where we enter the search the search string with the name "colValues".

Here is the code I used on the click of search the button:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet

Dim query As String = "select * from customer where " + colNames.SelectedValue.ToString + " LIKE " + "'%" + colValues.Text + "%'"

CustomerTableAdapter.Connection.Open()

Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(query, CustomerTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString)

adp.Fill(ds, "customer")

CustomerTableAdapter.Connection.Close()

filteredRecords.DataSource = ds

filteredRecords.DataMember = "customer"
```

The code above throws an exception on line 6 (adp.Fill(ds, "customer")): "The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRowView" could not be bound".

Please help me out debugging it or suggest a new code so that I can implement the search functionality.

Comment: DON'T DO THIS. http://www.google.co.uk/q=sql+injection and http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score -1):

The code below worked for me:

```
<br><br>Private Sub colValues_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles colValues.TextChanged
<br>Dim ds As New DataSet
<br>Dim query As String = "select * from customer where " + search_by.SelectedItem.ToString + " LIKE " + "'%" + colValues.Text + "%'"
<br>CustomerTableAdapter.Connection.Open()
<br>Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(query, CustomerTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString)
<br>adp.Fill(ds, "customer")
<br>CustomerTableAdapter.Connection.Close()
<br>filteredRecords.DataSource = ds
<br>filteredRecords.DataMember = "customer"
<br>End Sub
```

I wrote the whole code inside the text changed event of the search box.

In the above code, search_by is a list box which list various ccolumn names like- name, phone, address, etc. and colvalues is the name of the textbox where I entered the search string.